# Unable to make a UDP request

Tags: go

I am trying to build a BitTorrent client in go. I need to make UDP requests to connect to the various trackers. For this I use the `net` package and do this:

```
net.Dial("udp", "udp://hostname:1337/announce")
```

I get a "too many colons in address" error.

If I try this:

```
net.Dial("udp", "hostname:1337/announce")
```

I get a "nodename nor servname provided, or not known" error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Dial takes an IP address, not a URL. The path portion is not part of the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'll need to send it to the `IP` address and `port` as provided by the `.torrent` metafile (`announce` field).

And once you open the `net.Conn` you can `conn.Write()` to the socket and similarly `conn.Read()`

So you've just about gotten i:

```
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", announceAddr:Port)
```

When connecting with `HTTP`, yeah you use the `/announce` endpoint, but not with `UDP`

The [specs](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html) explain how many bytes to read and write (it is fixed at first, but later dynamic when it comes to reading the peer list). I've found this link, rather, the most useful: https://github.com/naim94a/udpt/wiki/The-BitTorrent-UDP-tracker-protocol